# Idempotents in quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents

> Let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y,Z]/(Y − X + 1, Y − Z + 2, 3X^2 - YZ + 3X +2Y + 4)$. What are the solutions $e \in R$ of the equation $e^2 = e$ with $e \not\in \{0,1\}$?

So $e$ has to be a residue class of a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X,Y,Z]$ modulo the ideal $(Y − X + 1, Y − Z + 2, 3X^2 - Y Z + 3X + 2Y +4)$.
Could someone explain to me how to find at least one solution?

I have already shown that $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}[T]/(2T+3)$, but I'm not sure you need it to solve my question?

Comment: Can you describe the idempotents in a ring of the form $R\times S$, assuming you know the idempotents of $R$ and of $S$?

Comment: You seem to have written two different ideals.

Comment: You're right about the two different ideals, I have changed it! But I really think that is $2T+3$, because $ℤ[X,Y,Z]/(Y−X+1,Y−Z+2,3X^2−YZ+3X+2Y+4) \cong ℤ[X,Y]/(Y−X+1,3X^2−Y^2+3X+4) \cong  ℤ[X]/(3X^2−(X-1)^2+3X+4) \cong ℤ[X]/(2X^2+5X+3) \cong ℤ[X]/(X+1)(2X+3) \cong ℤ[X]/(X+1) \times ℤ[X]/(2X+3) \cong ℤ×ℤ[T]/(2T+3)$